# Apple music not playing some songs in ios

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music

I am working with Apple music and using `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer` for playing music with the unique song `id(870697325)`. some song working fine but some does not work. it just displays the `nil` and `stops`. I have printed log please find it belove.

```
PlaybackStateDidChange------------nil---
PlaybackStateDidChange-----------playing----
Nil items
PlayingItemDidChange-----------playing----
Current durations :- 0.0 || Player durations :- 0.0 || Progress :- nan
Current durations :- 0.0 || Player durations :- 0.0 || Progress :- nan
PlayingItemDidChange-----------playing----
audioStreamingDidLogin
Current durations :- 266.0 || Player durations :- 0.0 || Progress :- 0.0
Current durations :- 266.0 || Player durations :- 0.0 || Progress :- 0.0
Current durations :- 266.0 || Player durations :- 0.0 || Progress :- 0.0
Current durations :- 266.0 || Player durations :- 0.0 || Progress :- 0.0
Current durations :- 266.0 || Player durations :- 0.0 || Progress :- 0.0
prepareToPlay----------------
PlaybackStateDidChange----------stopped-----
2018-10-22 11:40:41.162172+0530 ChuneApp[346:27769] [Middleware] FINISH Request: <MPCPlayerRequest: 0x125e3be90 label=MPMusicPlayerController playerPath=<MPCPlayerPath: route=<MPAVEndpointRoute: 0x123e3c480 name=iPhone uid=LOCAL> bundleID=com.apple.Music [system media app] playerID=Music>> Response: (null) [0.025357s] error: Error Domain=MPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={MPRequestUnderlyingErrorsUserInfoKey=(
    "Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=2000 \"Failed to get playing identifer\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get playing identifer}"
)}
2018-10-22 11:40:41.173490+0530 ChuneApp[346:26654] [Middleware] RRC <MPCPlayerRequest 0x123d12860>: Request failed with error: Error Domain=MPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={MPRequestUnderlyingErrorsUserInfoKey=(
    "Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=2000 \"Failed to get playing identifer\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get playing identifer}"
)}
PlaybackStateDidChange------------nil---
```

Is there any issue from the `apple` id? Can I play the same song from the `Indian Apple id` and `UK Apple id`? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have noticed that playing sometimes fails if I call prepare too soon. Try doing something like this:  [self performSelector:@selector(startPlaying) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.15]; to see if there is any difference.